# Removing a column whose header is blank from a dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following output from a R code:

```
trans_test11<- as.data.frame(t(test1))
trans_test11
              (Intercept)   IN_REC_COUNT    THROUGHPUT CPU_USAGE MEMORY_USAGE
coef(lin_mod)    178.4455 0.000006450854 -0.0006819742 -1.223342     7.275717
                      CAHCE_SIZE
coef(lin_mod) -0.000000002349061
```

I want to remove the row.names coef(lin_mod) field.
How can I do that?

```
The output should like the following:

(Intercept)   IN_REC_COUNT    THROUGHPUT   CPU_USAGE    MEMORY_USAGE    
178.4455      0.000006450854 -0.0006819742 -1.223342     7.275717
          CAHCE_SIZE
 -0.000000002349061
```

I need this because I need to load the data in a Table in an Oracle DB.

Comment: try `row.names(trans_test11) <- NULL`  But, it still will have 1, 2 as row names.  I don't know what format OracleDB takes the data.  Also, mentioned in the title that you want to remove a column, but in the description it is rownames.  Please provide the dput output for the example showed

Comment: If you are writing the data to a file, use `write.table(trans_test11, yourfile.txt, row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

Broadly speaking if your intention is to delete the column without a name you could do the following:

```
# Create column with no name for example
data(mtcars)
names(mtcars)[names(mtcars)=="cyl"] <- ""
# Remove column
keep.cols <- names(mtcars) %in% c("")
clean.crs <- mtcars [! keep.cols]
```

Comment: this works like a champ! Thanks!